# How can you select one of two individuals at random using a biased coin

Tags: self-study, randomness

Suppose you are given a biased coin for which the probability of getting a head is $p (0<p<1)$.Discuss how you will select one of two individuals at random using the biased coin.

Comment: Related: [C puzzle: Make a fair coin from a biased coin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5429045/1378672) and [Getting a Fair Toss From a Biased Coin](http://www.billthelizard.com/2009/09/getting-fair-toss-from-biased-coin.html).

Comment: Flip the coin. That's it. The choice will still be random, but it will be *biased*. If you want to try to make the choice .5 for each person, then see the link @Procrastinator gave.

Comment: A technique for making an *unbiased* selection using biased coin goes back to [Von Neumann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_coin#Fair_results_from_a_biased_coin).

Comment: @whuber What a nice trick Von Neumann came up with.

Comment: There are plenty of ways other than Von Neumann's. (One amusing method: buy something cheap with the coin and flip one of the coins you get for change.) A good answer to this question might describe more than one way and assess their properties, such as the bias (if the solution only approximates a fair coin) and the expected number of flips needed to make a selection.

Comment: One nice thing about the Von Neumann solution is that it does not require us to know how biased the coin is...

Answer (score 2):

As listed in the commments, the canonical way to generate an unbiased coin flip for a biased coin, as first proposed by Von Neumann, is as follows:

- Toss the coin twice.
- If the result is either both heads of both tails, discard and toss the coin twice again.
- Otherwise, (if they are different), record the outcome of the first coin toss.

Understanding why this works relies on the observation that if you have a biased coin that comes up heads with probability $p$, and if you flip the coin twice, then:

- The probability of HH is: $p^2$
- The probability of HT is: $p(1-p)$
- The probability of TH is:  $(1-p)p$
- The probability of TT is:  $(1-p)^2.$

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer to this long-standing question. Translating answers provided in comments into formal answers helps improve the quality of the site.